# Error when opening tmux directly from ssh connection

Tags: ssh, tmux

I try to open `tmux` automatically when I connect to my office Computer (Mac with macOS Catalina).
I found the following solution outlined in a few Answers and a few blog posts:

```
ssh <hostname> -t "tmux"
```

When I use this I get following error:

```
bash: tmux: command not found
```

I'm confused because I can open `tmux` once the ssh-connection is established but not directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that tmux installation path is not present in your PATH variable when you ssh.

Check what is the path for `tmux` installation on remote machine using `which tmux`. And verify if you can see that path in the output of following command.

```
ssh <hostname> "echo $PATH"
```

You can either use the full path

```
ssh <hostname> -t "/usr/bin/tmux"
```

or update the PATH settings for non-interactive shell.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it just now and with the full path it works.

Comment: Even using the full path I get the same error: bash: /usr/bin/tmux: No such file or directory. The second command has no issue running another executable in the same folder as tmux.